# Denavit-Hartenberg convention

Tags: forward-kinematics, dh-parameters

There are two different conventions that can determine **DH parameters**.   What is the difference between **Craig's** [1, Sec 3.4] convention and the **Spong** [2, Sec. 3.2] convention?
I know that both methods must have the same response.

[1]: Craig, John J. *Introduction to robotics: mechanics and control*. Addison-Wesley, 1989.

[2]: Spong, Mark W., Seth Hutchinson, and Mathukumalli Vidyasagar. *Robot modeling and control*. Wiley, 2006.

Answer (score 8):

Craig uses the [modified DH parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denavit%E2%80%93Hartenberg_parameters#Modified_DH_parameters), while Spong uses the [classic DH parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denavit%E2%80%93Hartenberg_parameters#Four_parameters).

The difference between them are the locations of the coordinates system attachment to the links: in the modified DH, the coordinates of frame $O_{i}$ is put on axis $i$, while in the classic DH convention the coordinates of frame $O_{i}$ is put on axis $i+1$.

**Update (2014.10.26)**

Reading Craig's book again, I noted that the modified DH matrix is also different because of the order of the applied transformations. I edited the Wikipedia link with the different DH matrix.

Answer (score 3):

You should read this paper: "[Lipkin 2005: A Note on Denavit-Hartenberg Notation in Robotics](https://web.archive.org/web/20121119091715/http://profesores.usfq.edu.ec:80/laurents/IME440/DETC2005-85460_DenavitHartenberg.pdf)".  It explains the **3** main DH parameter conventions and how they differ.

Comment: That link is down. Any chance you have a nother link for the paper?

Comment: I fixed the link to a more official source, although you will have to pay for the download.

Answer (score 2):

This is Best Youtube video which gives thorough explanation of **Denavit Hartenberg Algorithm and Parameters**

[Forward Kinematics: Denavit-Hartenberg Convention](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jXvAC7Uowvw&index=6&list=PLJzZfbLAMTelwaLxFXteeblbY2ytU2AxX)

Following is youtube channel by Prof. Yang Cao from University of British Columbia which covers all topics in Advanced Robotics. This is best place for learning robotics concepts for **Robotics Engineering.**

[Robot Modeling and Control](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLJzZfbLAMTelwaLxFXteeblbY2ytU2AxX)

Check it out.

Comment: I would humbly also suggest the short video lessons at https://robotacademy.net.au/?s=kinematics, nearly a million downloads -- Peter Corke, creator of Robot Academy