# Solution to Inverse Kinematics of a 6 DOF Articulated robot with a wrist joint

Tags: robotic-arm, inverse-kinematics

I'm working on getting a solution to the inverse kinematics of a 6DOF Articulated robot with a wrist joint.

I derived the robot's forward kinematics firstly, using these angles
$$θ_1 = 60.102$$
$$θ_2 = 65.220$$
$$θ_3 = 40.390$$
$$θ_4 = 70.215$$
$$θ_5 = 40.002$$
$$θ_6 = 30.211$$

Using these joint parameters, I found a total transformation matrix

$a_1 = 0.18;~~a_2 = 0.6;~~a_3 = 0.12;~~a_4 = 0;~~a_5 = 0;~~a_6 = 0;$

$d_1 = 0.4;~~d_2 = 0;~~d_3 = 0;~~d_4 = 0.62;~~d_5 = 0;~~d_6 = 0.115;$

$α_1 = 90;~~α_2 = 0;~~α_3 = -90;~~α_4 = 90;~~α_5 = -90;~~α_6 = 0;$

This is the resulting total transformation matrix:

$$-0.920890~~~0.342692~~~~0.185808~~~~-0.077297$$
$$-0.010244~~~0.455209~~~~-0.890326~~~-0.273985$$
$$-0.389689~~~-0.821795~~~-0.415687~~~0.845690$$
$$0.000000~~~~0.000000~~~~0.000000~~~~1.000000$$

Now, I'm trying to find an analytical Inverse Kinematic solution that will output the original joint angles I used for the robot's forward kinematics using the total transformation matrix I found.

I used this formula to find the first three angles by decoupling the robot. The output of $\theta_1$ is correct but the output of $\theta_2$ & $\theta_3$ are wrong.

$$θ_1 = atan2(y_c,x_c) + π$$
$$θ_3 = atan2(s3,c3)$$
$$θ_2 = atan2((z_c-d_1),\sqrt(x_c^2+y_c^2)) - atan2(a_3s_3,a_2+a_3c_3)$$

**KEY**

$$x_c = P_x - (d_6*r_{13})$$
$$y_c = P_y - (d_6*r_{23})$$
$$z_c = P_z - (d_6*r_{33})$$
$$s_3 = sine theta 3$$
$$s_3 = sqrt(1-c_3^2)$$
$$c_3 = cosine theta 3$$
$$c_3 = \frac {(x_c^2 + y_c^2 + (z_c-d_1)^2 - a_2^2 - a_3^2)}{(2*a_2*a_3)}$$
$$a_2,a_3,d_1 == robot link parameters, defined earlier$$

**Does someone know of another IK analytical method I can use that will get me my original joint angles?**

Comment: The problem is that for a 6-DOF arm there is not a unique set of angles that arrive at the solution

Comment: can you post the axis assignment of your robot at the home configuration ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't say which DH parameter conventions you are using, so it will be hard for users to help you.  And there are actually [three different DH parameter conventions](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/4778/110).

But what might be going on is that they are both valid solutions, but with different configurations.  A 6 DoF arm can have many different joint configurations which lead to the same end-effector pose.  Here is a simple 2D example:

[image: two different IK solutions]